# How do pass extra parameters from jQuery to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to pass an extra parameter :mobilejs => true from jQuery to a rails controller. How do I do that?

This...

```
var settings  = $.extend{  'url': url,
      'data' : '{mobilejs:true}',
      'success' : callback || function () {},
      'dataType' : 'script'
      }, options || {});
 $.ajax(settings);
```

creates this response from the server

```
 [2012-06-14 16:05:48] ERROR bad URI `/airports.js?{mobilejs:true}'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'data' : '{mobilejs:true}',
```

Has to be:

```
'data' : {mobilejs:true},
```

Comment: Correct, `data` takes a hash, not a string.

Comment: It works. So `:x => y` in rails is accomplished by adding `?x=y` to the url? Good to know.